# Mongodb document schema only with key information

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, document

I have database in MongoDB with some collections and documents.
I want the schema of the document in a collection showing only keys in document not showing values.

Example: If my document in collection is

```
{
  "name":"ram",
  "department":"cse",
  "age":"30"
}
```

Then i want the output from `db` as

```
{
  "name":"",
  "department":"",
  "age":""
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve document from mongodb in required format

I tried to achieve using mapreduce function but not able to get required result:

```js
db.MyCollectionName.mapReduce(function () {
  for (var key in this) {
    emit(key, null);
  }
}, function (key, stuff) {
  return null;
}, {"out": "allFieldNames"}, function (err, results) {
  var fields = db.collection('allFieldNames').distinct('_id');
  fields.then(function (data) {
    var finalData = {"status": "success", "fields": data};
    res.send(finalData);
    delteCollection(db, 'allFieldNames');
  }).catch(function (err) {
    res.send(err);
    delteCollection(db, 'allFieldNames');
  });
});
```

Comment: You use `update` method to modify a document in a collection. Here is the [update documentation with examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html).

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: How about getting one document from the collection with a `limit(1)` and do `Object.keys()` (dict in python) and map that to a required format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you needed it, just in case if you've any schema validation you could get keys from there, if not let's say fields in each document in a collection vary from other then each document has it's own schema i.e; it's own set of key-value pairs/fields, that case do you need keys for all docs in a collection or you don't have this scenario(all docs looks same) ? Anyway few things can be done easy with code, but with this query you can do it in MongoDB as well upto certain levels of a field :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $limit: 1 }, { $project: { data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } },
{
    $project:
    {
        "data": {
            $arrayToObject: {
                $map: {
                    input: '$data', as: 'each', in:
                    {
                        $switch:
                        {
                            branches: [
                                {
                                    case: { $eq: [{ $type: '$$each.v' }, 'object'] },
                                    then: { k: '$$each.k', v: { $arrayToObject: { $map: { input: { $objectToArray: "$$each.v" }, as: 'each', in: { k: '$$each.k', v: { $type: '$$each.v' } } } } } }
                                },
                                {
                                    case: { $isArray: "$$each.v" },
                                    then: {
                                        k: '$$each.k', v:
                                        {
                                            $map: {
                                                input: "$$each.v", as: 'each', in:
                                                {
                                                    $cond: [{ $eq: [{ $type: '$$each' }, 'object'] },
                                                    { $arrayToObject: { $map: { input: { $objectToArray: "$$each" }, as: 'each', in: { k: '$$each.k', v: { $type: '$$each.v' } } } } },
                                                    { $type: '$$each' }]
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            default: { k: '$$each.k', v: { $type: '$$each.v' } }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$data" } }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P_2V1IiTpYS)

**Note :** If you wanted to write aggregation output to a new collection use either [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html) or [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/index.html) .

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
As per my project necessity, all the collections in database have same schema and i have various databases related to my project.
But due to data sensitivity, I want to show only keys in the document, not values.
Is there any mongo command to show document data in this way

Comment: @reddychennuru : there is no such thing, you can try this to get keys, I can actually change this query a bit if needed only k's..